# How to get an entire document list printed 'in order' in C#

Tags: c#, foreach, processstartinfo

here is my code to print documents in a binding list

```
        PrintDialog printDialog = new PrintDialog();
        DialogResult dialogResult = printDialog.ShowDialog();
        

        if (dialogResult == DialogResult.OK)
        {

            foreach (Datei datei in dateienList)
            {
                if (datei.dateiAuswählen == true) //if selected
                {
                    PrinterSettings currentPrinterSettings = new PrinterSettings();
                    printDialog.PrinterSettings = currentPrinterSettings;
                    currentPrinterSettings.Copies = (short)datei.anzahlKopien;
                    ProcessStartInfo processInfo = new ProcessStartInfo()
                    {
                        Verb = "print",
                        CreateNoWindow = true,
                        FileName = datei.pfad,
                        WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden
                    };
                    Process process = new Process();
                    process.StartInfo = processInfo;
                    process.Start();
                    process.WaitForInputIdle();
                    process.WaitForExit();
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000); 
                }
            }
        }
```

The problem is that documents are not printed in order if the number of documents increases like 100 or more. After some are printed in the right order, documents are printed in a mixed order, which I want to prevent. I haven't figured out why but my assumption is the size of documents causes the problem.

So I thought maybe I can use a property in ProcessStartInfo class to set a range to the whole list of documents avoiding foreach loop, which would make the order more stable but not really successful so far. Is there any way to fix the problem?

Comment: please describe in more detailed the *expected* outcome and what you get *instead*. "documents are printed in a mixed order" is pretty bague, we have no clue about the data and how it should be oreded.

Comment: @MakePeaceGreatAgain Thanks for your comment. The right order should be in the listed order on Data Grid View where file names are listed. They are listed in accordance with the selection order on open file dialog. I could not how the file order is mixed as it is completely random after some documents are printed in order.

Comment: Is your printer spooling documents?  If you make the delay much longer (like 1 minute), do they print in order?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was Thread.Sleep. I deleted this line and it works without any delay and prints out in order.